# Rock-Paper-Scissors-Lizard-Spock C++ Pogram

Tags: c++, rock-paper-scissors

I'm writing the C++ program that involves a twist on Rock, Paper, Scissors. How the added Lizard and Spock affect the game is very simple and you could look it up if you want, but its not needed as I'm 99% sure my issue lies with the formatting of my if-else statements.

In every iteration, no matter what configuration the computer or the user chooses, the outcome is always the same - i.e. *"You win! :)"*. Even in the cases where the user should have tied, or the user should have lost. If you are experienced, you will probably very easily see where I am messing up, please take a look. I apologize for the confusing curly braces but inputting my code was being very finnicky so I had to add random indents to make it format.

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

srand(time(NULL));
int computer = rand() % 5 + 1;

int user = 0;

std::cout << "=============================================\n";
std::cout << "Rock    Paper    Scissors    Spock    Lizard!\n";
std::cout << "=============================================\n";
std::cout << "1) Rock\n";
std::cout << "2) Paper\n";
std::cout << "3) Scissors\n";
std::cout << "4) Lizard\n";
std::cout << "5) Spock\n";
std::cout << "\n";
std::cout << "Shoot!\n";

std::cin >> user;
std::cout << "Computer chose: " << computer << "\n";

if(user == 1){
if(computer == 3 || 4){
  std::cout << "You win! :)\n";
}
else if(computer == 1){
  std::cout << "You tied! :/\n";
}
else{
  std::cout << "Computer wins! :(\n";
}
    } 
else if(user == 2){
if(computer == 1 || 5){
  std::cout << "You win! :)\n";
}
else if(computer == 2){
  std::cout << "You tied! :/\n";
}
else{
  std::cout << "Computer wins! :(\n";
} 
 }
else if(user == 3){
if(computer == 2 || 4){
  std::cout << "You win! :)\n";
}
else if(computer == 3){
  std::cout << "You tied! :/\n";
}
else{
  std::cout << "Computer wins! :(\n";
}    
}
else if(user == 4){
if(computer == 2 || 5){
  std::cout << "You win! :)\n";
}
else if(computer == 4){
  std::cout << "You tied! :/\n";
}
else{
  std::cout << "Computer wins! :(\n";
} 
  }
else{
if(computer == 1 || 3){
  std::cout << "You win! :)\n";
}
else if(computer == 5){
  std::cout << "You tied! :/\n";
}
else{
  std::cout << "Computer wins! :(\n";
}
 }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review code that is working as expected and provide suggestions on how to improve that code. Questions about code that is not working as expected are off-topic for code review. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand more about the code review site. This help page does contain a link to where you can get help.

Comment: See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/213842/rock-paper-scissors-engine

Answer (score 1):

## Spacing

Before anything, I would recommend fixing your spacing and tabbing. Four spaces for each level of nesting is recommended. It makes your code *a lot* more readable.

## Bug

There is a pretty obvious bug in your code I noticed on my first pass. It's how you're checking the computers number versus the users number. For instance, take a look at this line:

```
if (user == 0 || 1)
```

To a novice, it looks like `if user == 0 OR user == 1`, but that is not happening here. Instead, this is only checking if user is equal to 0, OR if 1 is true. And 1 is always true. This can result in some unexpected behavior. Take a look:

```
if (user == 0 || 1) { 
    std::cout << "Greetings!" << std::endl; 
} else {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now, if I only enter `0`, I will get the expected output of just "Greetings!". However, if I enter literally any other number, I will instead only get "Greetings!", instead of getting "Hello!".

## Repetition

You have *tons* of repeated code. You can simplify this by first checking for if the computers input is the same as the users at the start of the program. Then you won't have to keep checking on the goat `if/else` chunk.

```
if (computer == user) {
    std::cout << "You tied! :/" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then, you can just assume the user loses at the start.

```
std::string message = "Computer wins! :(";
```

Now, you only have to check for win conditions, and if any are met, you change the message variable.

```
if (
    (user == 1 && (computer == 3 || computer == 4)) ||
    (user == 2 && (computer == 1 || computer == 5)) ||
    (user == 3 && (computer == 2 || computer == 4)) ||
    (user == 4 && (computer == 2 || computer == 5)) ||
    (user == 5 && (computer == 1 || computer == 3))
) message = "You win! :)";
```

Then, you just output the message variable.

```
std::cout << message << std::endl;
```

## End

All in all, with these changes made your code now looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    srand(time(NULL));
    int computer = rand() % 5 + 1;
    int user = 0;

    std::cout << "=============================================\n";
    std::cout << "Rock    Paper    Scissors    Spock    Lizard!\n";
    std::cout << "=============================================\n";
    std::cout << "1) Rock\n";
    std::cout << "2) Paper\n";
    std::cout << "3) Scissors\n";
    std::cout << "4) Lizard\n";
    std::cout << "5) Spock\n";
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Shoot!\n";

    std::cin >> user;
    std::cout << "Computer chose: " << computer << "\n";

    if (computer == user) {
        std::cout << "You tied! :/" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    std::string message = "Computer wins! :(";

    if (
        (user == 1 && (computer == 3 || computer == 4)) ||
        (user == 2 && (computer == 1 || computer == 5)) ||
        (user == 3 && (computer == 2 || computer == 4)) ||
        (user == 4 && (computer == 2 || computer == 5)) ||
        (user == 5 && (computer == 1 || computer == 3))
    ) message = "You win! :)";

    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they may make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Yeah I skimmed through the question and missed that they said it didn't work, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple mistakes

*Firstly*, your code does not have proper spacing, and it makes the code unreadable.

*Secondly*, there is a lot of repeating. When you must check a lot of conditions, consider using a `switch` or automate it in any way.

*Thirdly*, there is a bug in your `if` statement:

```
if (computer == 2 || 5)
```

Here the `if` operator will return `true` every time since `5` is not 0. You should rewrite it this way:

```
if (computer == 2 || computer == 5)
```

---

### Advanced advice

I found these rules in [another thread](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/36435/205644):
[image: Rules explained]
*Sorry for my bad drawing.*

What I recommend is to create an algorithm to find a winner. Looking at the "circle" above, you lose if your opponent has something in two steps ahead of you or one step behind.
Firstly, it is better to create an `enum` for storing these choices.

```
enum Choice: int
{ 
    ROCK = 0,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS,
    LIZARD,
    SPOCK,
    ITEMS_COUNT
};
```

Here I specified the `enum` type explicitly because I am using that number later in math with integers. The last element here contains exactly the number of choices as long as we do not change the values of previous items.

The next step is to find a winner using that rule mentioned above. We can find losing conditions in this simple way:

```
int lose1 = ( user + 2 ) % Choice::ITEMS_COUNT,
    lose2 = ( user - 1 ) % Choice::ITEMS_COUNT;
```

By calculating a modulus, we can keep our numbers from going out of bounds. Then we just need to compare these losing conditions with the computer's choice.

---

Another recommendation is about your menu output. String concatenation and `cout` pipe calls can hit your performance sometimes. In this specific situation, it is better to store the full menu table in Read-Only Memory and then just print it with `cout`. You will probably want to print it in a game loop, so it is better to move this code to a function. You can also make it `inline` as the function is quite small.

```
inline void printMenu()
{
    static const std::string menu =
    "=============================================\n"
    "Rock    Paper    Scissors    Spock    Lizard!\n"
    "=============================================\n"
    "1) Rock\n"
    "2) Paper\n"
    "3) Scissors\n"
    "4) Lizard\n"
    "5) Spock\n"
    "\n"
    "Shoot!\n";
    std::cout << menu;
}
```

---

Last but not least, you should check the input because it can crash your app. Consider using `while` loop with a `cin.fail()` and bounds check. You can write something like this:

```
int user = -1;
printMenu();
std::cin >> user;
while(std::cin.fail() || user < 0 || user > 5)
{
    std::cout<<"Error!\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    printMenu();
    std::cin>>user;
}
```

`cin.clear()` is important here as it resets the fail state.

---

### Code

Here is my code for this problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Choice: int
{ 
    ROCK = 0,
    PAPER,
    SCISSORS,
    LIZARD,
    SPOCK,
    ITEMS_COUNT
};

int userWon(const int&, const int&);

inline void printMenu();

int getInput();

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int user = getInput();
    int computer = rand() % 5 + 1;
    std::cout << "Computer chose: " << computer << "\n";
    int result = userWon(user, computer);
    if( result == 1)
        std::cout << "You win!";
    else if ( result == -1 )
        std::cout << "Computer wins!";
    else
        std::cout << "Tie!";
    
    return 0;
}

inline void printMenu()
{
    static const std::string menu =
    "=============================================\n"
    "Rock    Paper    Scissors    Spock    Lizard!\n"
    "=============================================\n"
    "1) Rock\n"
    "2) Paper\n"
    "3) Scissors\n"
    "4) Lizard\n"
    "5) Spock\n"
    "\n"
    "Shoot!\n";
    std::cout << menu;
}

int getInput()
{
    int user = -1;
    printMenu();
    std::cin >> user;
    while(std::cin.fail() || user < 0 || user > 5)
    {
        std::cout<<"Error!\n";
        std::cin.clear();
        printMenu();
        std::cin>>user;
    }
    return user;
}

int userWon(const int& user, const int& computer)
{
    int res = 0;
    if( user != computer )
    {
        int lose1 = ( user + 2 ) % Choice::ITEMS_COUNT,
            lose2 = ( user - 1 ) % Choice::ITEMS_COUNT;
        if( computer == lose1 || computer == lose2 )
            res = -1;
        else
            res = 1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they may make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.

Comment: Lizard -> Paper arrow missing. Each node should have two out and two in.